# Can't open external browser: cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am building an app which uses cordova-plugin-inappbrowser for iOS.
On Android this plugin works perfectly fine but on iOS when I click a link to the website it opens within the app.
I would like this to open in the systems default external browser.

When I try to open, it shows below error.

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating ‘$window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open’)
```

I've tried on some solutions mentioned on website but didnt work.

What I have already tried on are

1. change `$window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system");` to `window.open(url, "_system");`
   => the website opens within the app not the default browser
2. couldn't remove plugin via command so deleted all files from a folder and tried `$cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` 
   => error `Invalid Version: broken`
3. addeed `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="version”>`  to config.xml
   => build error
4. added `<feature name="InAppBrowser"><param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser"/>` to ios config
   => error `Unhandled error. ('Parsing /config.xml failed')`
5. added `<preference name="InAppBrowserStatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />` to config.xml
   => build success but nothing's changed

Platform and Version

- Cordova v9.0.0
- ios 5.1.1
- X-code 13.2.1
- Node.js 16.16.0
- iPhone 15.5

├── cordova-android@9.0.0
├── cordova-ios@5.1.1
├── cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter@1.1.3 (git+ssh://git@github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter.git#2166b075d271103f84efc0d19b0f0ca1372cad2c)
├── cordova-plugin-customurlscheme@5.0.2
├── cordova-plugin-fcm@2.1.2 (git+ssh://git@github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm.git#161d02dcebd0d798e017a2d16bc016b930da97b2)
├── cordova-plugin-file@6.0.2
├── cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@5.0.1-dev (git+ssh://git@github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git#bd02f453833c6ed9cd2b8d27212966a23fa0af13)
├── cordova-plugin-network-information@3.0.1-dev (git+ssh://git@github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information.git#fcec956c1fd055e3a586b81eb2137bd7cee6f620)
├── cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.3.6-dev (git+ssh://git@github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git#9fafd026c4c10a60b61efb46344defe6da7b1861)
├── cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine@1.2.2
├── cordova.plugins.diagnostic@6.1.1
├── mkdirp@1.0.4
└── phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@8.1.1-dev (git+ssh://git@github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git#bd82b3f54802b3d70cd81d6b3d0f3bd6e11332d7)

Any help and advice will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: shared more code

Comment: Like what code should I share more?

Comment: when you open link in inappbrowser

Comment: `window.open(google.com, "_system");` like this? then this will open google page within the cordova app....

Comment: `https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser` check this link, import `InAppBrowser` in app.module.ts file inside `providers`